# Create a collection in XAML and bind individual collection items

Tags: wpf, xaml, .net-3.5

I've created a custom control which, when bound to a custom collection of objects, displays the content of those objects.

Usually, I can use this control by simply going:

```
<local:CustomCollectionDisplayer DataContext="{Binding Source={x:Static Application.Current}, Path=SomeObject.InstanceOfCustomeCollectionOfCustomItems}" />
```

My problem now comes where I want to recycle this control to show only a single object. In the xaml, I want to make a custom collection where the only item in the collection is bound to that single object.

The code looks like this:

```
<local:CustomCollectionDisplayer>
    <local:CustomCollectionDisplayer.DataContext>
        <local:CustomCollection>
            <local:CustomItem Reference="{Binding Source={x:Static Application.Current}, Path=SomeObject.InstanceOfCustomItem}"/>-->
        </local:CustomCollection>
    </local:CustomCollectionDisplayer.DataContext>
</local:CustomCollectionDisplayer>
```

Obviously, there's no 'Reference' property which I can use to make the CustomItem in the collection point to the instance of CustomItem in 'SomeClass'. How can I achieve this without creating a dummy CustomCollection containing this CustomItem in my object viewmodel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There already is a [`x:Reference` markup extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee795380.aspx), but it is very limited as it only gets objects by name. You could write your own [markup-extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee855815.aspx) which can get properties. e.g.

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Markup;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace Test.MarkupExtensions
{
    [ContentProperty("Object")]
    public class GetExtension : MarkupExtension
    {
        public object Object { get; set; }
        public string PropertyName { get; set; }

        public GetExtension() { }
        public GetExtension(string propertyName)
            : this()
        {
            if (propertyName == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("propertyName");
            PropertyName = propertyName;
        }

        public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            if (PropertyName == null)
                throw new InvalidOperationException("PropertyName cannot be null");
            if (Object == null)
            {
                var target = (IProvideValueTarget)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IProvideValueTarget));
                Object = target.TargetObject;
            }
            var prop = Object.GetType().GetProperty(PropertyName);
            if (prop == null)
                throw new Exception(String.Format("Property '{0}' not found on object of type {1}.", PropertyName, Object.GetType()));
            return prop.GetValue(Object, null);
        }
    }
}
```

Which could be used like this:

```
<local:CustomCollectionDisplayer>
    <local:CustomCollectionDisplayer.DataContext>
        <local:CustomCollection>
            <me:Get PropertyName="InstanceOfCustomItem">
                <me:Get PropertyName="SomeObject" Object="{x:Static Application.Current}"/>
            </me:Get>
        </local:CustomCollection>
    </local:CustomCollectionDisplayer.DataContext>
</local:CustomCollectionDisplayer>
```

You could also resolve a whole [`PropertyPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.propertypath.aspx) at once in the extension if you prefer that, this is just a sketchy example.

---

Another option is to bind the `DataContext` directly to the object and wrap it in the collection using a [`Converter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.converter.aspx).

Comment: Sorry, I probably should have mentioned .Net3.5

Comment: @Alain: What does it matter? I did not tell you to use `x:Reference`, i only mentioned it.

Comment: I was clarifying. In any event - for this question, my example was quite simple, the actual property I want to resolve is nested fairly deeply, {x:Static Application.Current}.Hub.Class.Control.Object.Property sort of thing. It might also use advanced binding syntax such as FindAncestor and RelativeSource. Is there a way to do this using a standard binding syntax?

Comment: @Alain: Usually there is not, unless you write a resolver yourself. Bindings can only be set on DPs so you cannot add items to a collection using bindings, you could only replace the whole collection. *(So if your `CustomCollection`'s item property is actually a DP you could probably apply a binding but you would need to use a covnerter to wrap the bound object in the respective property-collection-type)*

Comment: The custom collection does extend ObservableCollection, but that probably doesn't mean anything. Looks like my only options are to create a named CustomCollection in the xaml and programatically add my CustomItem to it on construction, or bind to a dummy CustomCollection in the viewmodel. True?

Comment: @Alain: I just saw that the custom collection is not a needed wrapper, basically you just want a single-item CustomCollection in the DataContext, right? Then you can just bind the DataContext directly to that item (if a binding can completely point to it) and add a [`Binding.Converter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.converter.aspx) which creates a new `CustomCollection` and adds the bound item to it. Shouldn't that work? Or do you want to avoid converters or need the collection to exist in XAML?

Comment: While creating a collection for the item in the viewmodel was the simple solution I went with, creating a converter which returns a collection containing the item is actually pretty ingenious. You're full of great ideas. Seriously - points for creativity.